# IIS 8.5 not showing the ssl sign on the left of the URL

Tags: ssl, iis

Hello I have a problem with an IIS 8.5 server where I have a 3.8 joomla. the problem is that I have installed the certificate and every time I enter the page only the sign of the certificate appears for a moment and then disappears I have configured the firewall and the URLs have also changed the .htacces and nothing seems to be a clear solution .

And there are times when I get a 403.3 error when I activate the ssl request in the ISS.

Comment: Can you post logs? Also, have you tried enabling failed request logging in IIS? That output would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, check if the https connection was established by checking the certificate

Chrome:- Press F12; click on security and view certificate; ALso check if the padlock is available.

If the padlock is not visible but https is shown on the address bar, then this seems to be an issue with mixed content. In short http links (images, codes) are served over https .